# Binded value not refreshed when source Updates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

## Context

I have a custom Button that you bind to a boolean that will change style depending on the bool value.

Here is the behind code I use:

```
public bool Boolean
{
    get => (bool)this.GetValue(BooleanProperty);
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(BooleanProperty, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty BooleanProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Boolean", typeof(bool), typeof(BooleanButton),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public BooleanButton() : base()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.PropertyChanged += DataContext_PropertyChanged;
    this.Click += ButtonControl_Click;
}

private void DataContext_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //changing style
}

private void ButtonControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean = !Boolean;
}
```

## Problem

As it is now, if I click the button, the source property is well modified, but if the property is changed from somewhere else in the code, the PropertyChanged event is not fired, and I can't update my style accordingly

Comment: Be aware that it is pointless to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties. They do already provide their own change notification mechanism.

Comment: Would this be the reason of the problem I'm facing?

Comment: You need to register a PropertyChangedCallback.